# Woocommerce_message dissapeared and was replaced with added_to_cart

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I've styled the class woocommerce_message and continued on with developing my theme. I needed to add wp_footer();  to the bottom of my code to make the lightbox functionality work and now when I click "add to cart" what appears is added_to_cart underneath the add to cart button. Also if I add a product with stock quantity 1 twice it will give me the desired woocommerce_error but it opens in the unavailable products page and I want to know how to put it back/why it happened.

When I take wp_footer(); out it fixes the problem but I need it to make lightbox work.

I'm developing it locally so I can't share site link but I've put a zip file containing all the theme code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/57m63w98ntds1or/Vintage%20Then%20Today.zip?dl=0